# How to express Cantor's Normal Form Theorem in first order logic?

Tags: set-theory, first-order-logic

Sorry, I don't have enough reputation to post a picture, so here's a link:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/XxYif.png

The above theorem is proved using transfinite induction, but this relies on there being a first order predicate expressing "this ordinal may be expressed in the cantor normal form" for this to follow from the axioms of ZFC. I am looking for a brief sketch of how one could go about doing this.

I think part of what has me stumped is the fact that n can vary so I can't simply just put a fixed number of existential quantifiers in my first order formula.

Comment: You have to find a way to manage the "variable" number of "coefficient" of the normal form... You can try coding a *sequence* of lenght $k$.

Comment: so something like "there exists a sequence of length k that contains elements of the given form and if f is a recursive function on this sequence defined by the rule of successively adding these terms, then f(k-1) = the ordinal". Am I on the right track?

Comment: You can define a finite sequence of length $n,$ for  $0\ne n\in \omega,$ as a function $g$ with domain $n$.